# How would using scanf like gets work?

Tags: c, scanf, gets

What would be the best way to imitate the functionality of `gets` with `scanf`?

Here is my current attempt

```
 int main()
 {
    char cvalue[20];   //char array to store input string
    int iloop=0;      //integer variable for loop

    for(iloop=0;iloop<20;iloop++)     // for loop to get the string char by char
    {
        scanf("%c",&cvalue[iloop]); //getting input
        if(cvalue[iloop]=='\n')    //if input is newline skip further looping
        break;
    }                    // end of loop

    cvalue[iloop]='\0';         //set end of the character for given input
    printf("%s",cvalue);        //printing the given string
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to learn how to [format your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). I've also phrased your question to better suit the SO question format. First ask the question clearly, then show your current attempt.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `scanf` this way to work like `gets`

```
scanf("%[^\n]",&a);
```

Comment: This appears to fail to consume the `\n` in the input like `gets()`.  `gets()` reads '\n' , but does not stored it in `&a`.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt doesn't really imitate `gets()`, since `gets()` just keeps putting bytes into the supplied buffer until the end of line is reached. You should realize then that `gets()` is dangerous and should be avoided. It does not offer any protection from buffer overflow. So, it is also questionable to imitate it.

Given that, your attempt has a couple flaws that I see. First, it loops to the complete size of the input buffer. This doesn't leave you any room to store the NUL terminator if the input line is 20 bytes or longer. This means that you may attempt to store the `\0` at `cvalue[20]`, which outside the array boundary. You can fix this by shortening your `for` loop by one:

```
    for(iloop=0;iloop<19;iloop++)     // for loop to get the string char by char
```

The second flaw is that you do not check to see if the `scanf()` call succeeds. If you detect failure, you should also leave the loop:

```
        if (scanf("%c",&cvalue[iloop]) != 1) { //getting input
            break;
        }
```

---

Below was my attempt at creating a safer version of `gets()` implemented with `scanf()`.

```
char *getsn (char *s, size_t sz) {
    char c;
    char fmt[sizeof(sz) * CHAR_BIT + sizeof("[^\n]")];
    if (sz == 0) return 0;
    if (sz == 1) {
        s[0] = '\0';
        return s;
    }
    s[sz-2] = '\0';
    snprintf(fmt, sizeof(fmt), "%%%lu%s", (unsigned long)sz-1, "[^\n]");
    switch (scanf(fmt, s)) {
    case 0:  s[0] = '\0';
             scanf("%c", &c);
             return s;
    case 1:  scanf("%c", &c);
             if (s[sz-2] != '\0' && c != '\n') {
                 ungetc(c, stdin);
             }
             return s;
    default: break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The safer version uses `snprintf()` to create a format string that limits how many characters should be stored by the `scanf()`. So if the provided `sz` parameter was 100, the resulting format string would be `"%99[^\n]"`. Then, it makes sure to only strip out the `\n` from the input stream if it was actually encountered.

Comment: Novel use of `printf()` to create the maximum field width for `scanf(fmt, s)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to observe the usually dangers of `gets()`.

The challenge to using `scanf()` is
1) Insuring that `\n` is consumed.  `scanf("%[^\n]",...` does not do this.
2) Insuring the `str` gets a `\0` if only a `\n` is read.
3) Dealing with EOF and I/O errors and return `0`.
4) Insure leading whitespace are read into `str` as `scanf("%s"` skips them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// On success, the gets() returns str.
// If EOF encountered, the eof indicator is set (feof).
// If this happens before any characters could be read, 
//    pointer returned is a null pointer.
//  If a read error occurs, the error (ferror) is set
//    and a null pointer is also returned.
char *gets_via_scanf( char * str ) {
  // Reads characters from stdin & saves them into str until \n or the end-of-file.
  // \n, if found, is not copied into str.
  int retval = scanf("%[^\n]",str);  // %[ does not skip leading whitespace
  if (retval == EOF) return 0;
  if (retval == 0) {
    *str = '\0';  // Happens when users only types in \n
  }
  char ch;
  scanf("%c",&ch); // Consume leftover \n, could be done with getc()
  return str;
}
```